# Carrierwave getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm currently fighting to get S3 uploads to work via Carrierwave, Carrierwave-aws & Figaro.

But I keep getting

**SocketError in OffersController#create**

**getaddrinfo: Name or service not known**

I've tried changing asset host to '127.0.0.1' still appears to produce this error.

**carrierwave.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage    = :aws
  config.aws_bucket = ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME')
  config.aws_acl    = 'public-read'

  # Optionally define an asset host for configurations that are fronted by a
  # content host, such as CloudFront.
  config.asset_host = 'localhost'

  # The maximum period for authenticated_urls is only 7 days.
  config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

  # Set custom options such as cache control to leverage browser caching
  config.aws_attributes = {
    expires: 1.week.from_now.httpdate,
    cache_control: 'max-age=604800'
  }

  config.aws_credentials = {
    access_key_id:     ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    region:            ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION') # Required
  }

end
```

**gemfile**

```
# Figaro
gem "figaro"

# Carrierwave Integration
gem 'carrierwave'

# Carrierwave AWS
gem 'carrierwave-aws'
```

Any help on this would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove `config.asset_host = 'localhost'` from your `CarrierWave.configure`. It's optional and mainly use to set third party assets path like cloudfront.

SO remove `config.asset_host = 'localhost'` and you are done.

Comment: Unfortunately on remove - I also get the same error? I'm guessing it's defaulting to something?